# In haskell, What does :+: mean in data type definition?

Tags: haskell

This is the definition for a new data type:

```
data Total a = Total a :+: Total a 
              |...
```

What does :+: mean in this type definition?

Comment: It's not valid in standard Haskell.  It's a weird GHC extension :)

Comment: @singpolyma: It's standard [Haskell 98 syntax](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/syntax-iso.html) (see the _consym_ production). After all, the `:` constructor for lists is just a special case of this. Perhaps you were thinking of `TypeOperators`?

Comment: @hammar Oh, hmm, I was thinking of `TypeOperators`.  I wasn't aware using operators for data constructors was standard.  It's very ugly.  Usually ugly things are extensions :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a data constructor written in infix form. You can have an operator as constructor if it begins with `:` .

Comment: To put it flippantly, `:` is an upper case symbol :D

Comment: Note that, as of GHC 7.6, the `TypeOperators` extension now treats all infix operators as "uppercase". (Which breaks existing code that used infix operators as type variables...)

Comment: @user1720938: For visual symmetry. Purely an aesthetic thing.

Comment: @C.A.McCann: Only at the type level, surely? Otherwise `(+)` would be a constructor name, not a value name, and this question is about constructor names.

Comment: To add some context to @C.A.McCann's comment that may not be immediately clear: when using symbols in _type expressions_ like `Int + Char`, the extension treats all symbols as "upper case". In the value sphere, `:` remains the only upper case symbol, value constructor symbols must begin with `:` still.

Comment: @ehird: Right, I should have been a bit more explicit there--as Daniel Fischer says, it makes the rules about what is considered "uppercase" differ for type-level identifiers (including type constructors) vs. data constructors, whereas before they were consistent. So the flippant remark about `:` being "uppercase" is not quite so accurate as it would previously have been.